# JAVA REGEX - Split a string with "?" as delimiter

Tags: java, regex

I want to split a string with "?" as the delimiter.

`str.split("?")[0]` fails.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The argument to the "split" method must be a regular expression, and the '?' character has special meaning in regular expressions so you have to escape it. That's done by adding a backslash before it in the regexp. However, since the regexp is being supplied by way of a Java String, it requires two backslashes instead so as to get an actual backslash character into the regexp:

```
str.split( "\\?" )[0];
```

Comment: +1 for explaining *why* you need to escape `?`, rather than just giving code.

Answer (score 2):

```
str.split("\\?")[0]
```

Comment: (Explanation: the argument to `String.split` is actually a regular expression and not plain text. Not one of Java's best bits of design, this.)

Comment: ... because `?` is a special character in regular expressions it has to be escaped with \ and \ has to be escaped with \ in Java.

Comment: maybe because the split method does not have a capital S? :)

Comment: @Fortega: Thanks for the edit. If I downvoted every time I encountered a typo on this site then I reckon my index finger would have worn away by now!